# How do I refresh a repeat that is updated using a dialog

Tags: xpages

I'm having a problem getting a repeat to refresh when the underlying value is changed using a dialog.

This is the div that contains the repeat:

```
<xp:div style="display:none;">
    <xp:inputText id="linkages" value="#{procureDoc.Linkages}" multipleTrim="true" style="color:cornflowerblue;" multipleSeparator=";">
    </xp:inputText>
</xp:div>
<xp:label value="Linkages:" id="linkageLabel" style="font-weight:bold;"></xp:label>
<xp:div id="linkageDiv">
    <ul>
        <xp:repeat id="linkagesDisplayRepeat" rows="30" var="rowData" indexVar="index" value="#{procureDoc.Linkages}">
            <li>
                <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField7">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowData;}]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:text>
            </li>
        </xp:repeat>
    </ul>
</xp:div>
```

Here's the save button from the dialog. It does happen to sit in another custom control, but I don't think that's the problem.

```
<xp:button value="Save" id="saveButton">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[var linkageSelection = document.getElementById("#{id:linkageComboBox}").value;
var linkageUpload = "";
if (linkageSelection == "Use Category") { 
    linkageUpload = document.getElementById("#{id:linkageCategoryComboBox}").value; 
}
else { linkageUpload = linkageSelection;}
var currentLinkages = document.getElementById("#{id:linkages}").value;
if ( currentLinkages == "" ) {
    document.getElementById("#{id:linkages}").value = linkageUpload;
} else {
    document.getElementById("#{id:linkages}").value = document.getElementById("#{id:linkages}").value + ";" + linkageUpload;
}
XSP.closeDialog('#{id:linkageDialog}');]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

I can put a button on the XPage that just refreshes and it will refresh my repeat with the value selected in the dialog, but just using my save button doesn't do it.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I just can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the onComplete event from your SSJS eventhandler to call a CSJS script like

```
XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:linkagesDisplayRepeat}");
```

to refresh the repeat control.

Comment: Shouldn't the refreshMode="complete" be doing a refresh, though?

Comment: Indeed, it should load the whole page. Is the repeat set tp partial refresh mode?

Comment: I don't understand "repeat set to partial refresh mode". All the code is above and I can't find a setting for partial refresh on the repeat itself.

Comment: Ah sorry the partial refresh corresponds to a pager that is used for a repeat - but you don't have one. What about the CSJS partial refresh I suggested? Did it work?

Answer (score 1):

There's a second parameter to the client-side closeDialog() method, denoting the ID of the component to partially refresh. That basically adds the onComplete for you.

SSJS corresponding method uses the ID of the component to subsequently refresh as the only parameter (obviously the method is called on the component being closed, which is the first parameter in CSJS).